# React-redux-firebase: Uncaught Error: Supplied prop/s "dispatch" are reserved for internal firebaseConnect() usage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-redux-firebase

I am using Routing recipe for users to be able to view/redirect between pages depending if user is logged in or not (https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/next/docs/recipes/routing.md-react-routerv4+redux-auth-wrapperv2).

When I log out it does redirect to a Login page but stays blank and I got the error:

```
"Uncaught Error: Supplied prop/s "dispatch" are reserved for internal firebaseConnect() usage."
```

My `Login.js` component is using `firebaseConnect()`. Is there an issue if one component is using firebase and it is used on another component that is using firebase too?

In tutorial I am following, versions of firebase, react-redux-firebase do differ but I did set up everything according to docs and trying to use most up to date versions. I do not know if that has anything to do with the issue.

From App.js:

```
<Route
   exact
   path="/login"
   component={UserIsNotAuthenticated(Login)}
/>
```

from Login.js:

```
onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { firebase } = this.props;
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    firebase
      .login({
        email,
        password
      })
      .catch(err => alert('Invalid Login Credentials'));
  };

export default firebaseConnect()(Login);
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "firebase": "^6.0.2",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^3.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-auth-wrapper": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.7.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue. As going through Docs (http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/recipes/routing.html), `UserIsNotAuthenticated` is used directly in component, not on the route level, and along with `withFirebase`.

So it looks like this:
App.js - remove `UserIsNotAuthenticated` on `Login` route:

`<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />`

Login.js:

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { withFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { UserIsNotAuthenticated } from '../../helpers/auth';
```

...

```
export default compose(
  UserIsNotAuthenticated,
  withFirebase
)(Login);
```

Now everything works. Once logged in, you are redirected from login page to home page and when you log out you are redirected to login page.